# display ajax result on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to display the results of an ajax request on a new page rather than the page the ajax call was made from. Essentially I have a membership directory page. When the user clicks on the member ID cell on that page, an ajax call sends the ID  to the server and completes an HTML table to display that member profile. If I add a `<div>` element below the membership directory page, I can make the profile information table display below the membership directory table. But I want the profile table to display on different page.

JavaScript:

```
$jq.ajax({
    url : ajax_mmmp.ajax_url,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action: 'mmmp_profile_member_id_callback',
        mem_id : member_id
    },
    success:function(data) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        console.log(data);
        // Return response to client side
            alert("Submit Success");
            $jq('#display_profile').html( data );

            return false;
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
}); // End of AJAX function
```

But when I create a new page with the same `<div>` element and try to open that page prior to the ajax call, the result does not display.

```
var mem_profile = "http://localhost:81/wordpress/view-member-profile"
window.open (mem_profile,'_self',false)

$jq.ajax({
    url : ajax_mmmp.ajax_url,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action: 'mmmp_profile_member_id_callback',
        mem_id : member_id
    },
    success:function(data) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        console.log(data);
        // Return response to client side
            alert("Submit Success");
            $jq('#display_profile').html( data );

            return false;
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
}); // End of AJAX function
```

Comment: Then use a normal form submit and set the target of the form to a new tab.  If you want to display results in a new page, using ajax doesn't make sense.

Comment: "I would like to display the results of an ajax request on a new page rather than the page the ajax call was made from"...this defeats the whole purpose of ajax, which is to allow you to _stay on the same page_. There already exists a mechanism to do what you want - it's a called a regular, traditional, bog-standard form postback. As mentioned, you can target the postback to a new window/tab if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the question of whether it is a good idea to take that approach, the answer to your question is yes. You can open a new window and write the resulting HTML to it:

```
// open a new window with no url and a title. check the docs for other args to open()
let win = window.open('','My New Window');
// write some HTML to that window
win.document.write('<table><tr><th>test</th></tr></table>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am a newbie in the learning process. I will look into the suggestions made and see if I can fit them into what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, I'm almost there. I do not presently have a "form" to submit. The user simply clicks on a table cell which contains a member ID number. I want to 'submit' that value as input on another page which displays the membership profile. I have been successful in temporarily adding a HTML form that works as desired if I type the member ID in an input field. So I decided what was needed was to create a hidden form in JS that used the ID value that was clicked on. It appears that I can not insert revised code into a comment, so I opted to 'Answer' my original question with updated code.

Working HTML Form included on Membership Directory Page:

```
$site_url = site_url();
$location = $site_url . "/view-member-profile";

?>

<form action="<?php echo $location;?>" method="post">
<input type="text" class="input_member_id" id="input_member_id" name="Member_ID">
<input type="submit" id="submit_member_id" name="submit_member_id" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My attempt to create a similar hidden form in JS:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

$jq(document).ready(function(){

// Add listener for Member ID click in member directory

$jq("#mem_dir").delegate(".member_id", "click", function() {
    var mem_id = $jq(this).text();
    var mem_id = mem_id.trim();
    alert ("ID is: " + mem_id);

    var site_url = document.location.origin + '/wordpress';
    var form_location = site_url + '/view-member-profile';
    alert ("Submit to location is: " + form_location);

    var form = $jq('<form method="post" class="js:hidden">').attr('action', form_location);
    //var input = $jq('<input type="hidden"'>).attr('value', mem_id );
    //form.append(input);
    //$jq('body').append(form);
    form.submit();

}); // End of Click Member ID Listener

}); // End of Main Document Ready Function
```

The problem I am having with the JS file is with inserting the mem_id value into the input form. The JS file correctly opens the new View Member Profile page. (Note the 3 // lines just prior to the form.submit). When uncommented, the Profile page opens, but table values are empty (i.e. mem_id value was not passed to the page).

Thanks for any advice. If I was supposed to list this as a new question, please let me know.

Comment: I resolved my problem. I had forgotten to include a 'name' for the input field in the JS file that I was retrieving via $_POST. The revised JS input file now looks like this:

`var input = $jq('<input type="hidden" name="Member_ID">').attr('value', mem_id );`

and is retrieved in the member profile page with:

`$member_id = $_POST[Member_ID];`

Thanks for all that helped.